# How do I permanently disable scroll lock in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, scroll-lock

I keep hitting scroll lock by mistake when I do a CTRL-ALT-BREAK. How do I permanently disable it?

- Running Windows XP
- This is a Lenovo laptop if it makes a difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable the "Scroll Lock" using a key remapper like "SharpKeys" check this link for more info http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/

Comment: Upon reading the app's FAQ, it seems it is a permanent solution, as it involves modifying the registry. It works on Windows XP so if you're not planning to upgrade your OS this should work, unless there's something funky in your keyboard. Resort to the app's FAQ if that happens.

Comment: Might try my own registry fix rather than downloading the app to do it for me (following an article linked from that one)..

Comment: Added `Scancode Map` regedit key with this value: `00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 46 00 00 00 00 00` - problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. I don't know if Lenovo ships some sort of keyboard-controller but if it does (as for Microsoft desktop keyboards) then there might be some sort of option.

If not, try to poke around your BIOS for some sort to disable the button, as indicated in [this](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Other-Notebook-PC-Questions/how-can-i-turn-off-the-scroll-lock-i-do-not-see-a-key-on-my/td-p/1869369) (although it is for an HP laptop).

Other that that, maybe someone somewhere made a program that removed the Scroll Lock action.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get some kind of software for re-assigning keyboard keys, and either assign the Scroll Lock key to launch something, or simply completely de-assign it from functioning at all. Easy-peasy.