# How to disable scroll lock key in linux, permanently?

Tags: linux, keymap, scroll-lock

My computer (Asus) doesn't have Scroll lock key;

yet it's getting magically pressed, changing Libreoffice Calc behavior.

- There are multiple answers for [Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/632525/how-do-i-permanently-disable-scroll-lock-in-windows-xp), and/or specific computer [manufacturer](https://superuser.com/questions/1279834/how-to-toggle-scroll-lock-in-an-hp-laptop-without-a-scroll-lock-key) --> but none about linux.
- The Asus undocumented Fn+PrtSc --> didn't work on Linux (ubuntu).

Is there a keymap to delete, or some special settings in the bios, or anything?

.... because LibreOffice doesn't have an off-switch for this feature.

Answer (score 3):

Answer from https://askubuntu.com/a/1072497/484668 helped me -

`dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options`

Then remove the 'grp_led:scroll' part and write it back like so:

`dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options "['grp:alt_shift_toggle']"`

Comment: thanks. I can't verify it since I replaced the distro, and the problem is gone.

Comment: Thanks, I can verify this works!